# Composing tensor bifunctor with hom functor

Tags: category-theory, modules, abelian-categories

Let $C$ be a commutative ring and let $C$Mod denote the category of modules over $C$. We have the bifunctors $\text{Hom}_C:C\text{Mod}^{\text{op}}\times C\text{Mod}\rightarrow C\text{Mod}$ and $\otimes_C:C\text{Mod}\times C\text{Mod}\rightarrow C\text{Mod}$. Fix $X,Y\in C\text{Mod}$. Then $X\otimes_CY\in C\text{Mod}$ and we have a functor
$$\text{Hom}_C(-,X\otimes_CY):C\text{Mod}^{\text{op}}\rightarrow C\text{Mod}.$$
I want to compose this functor with $\otimes_C$. But I want to consider the functor $\text{Hom}_C(-\otimes_C-,X\otimes_CY)$ from $C\text{Mod}^{\text{op}}\times C\text{Mod}$ instead of $C\text{Mod}\times C\text{Mod}$. This would mean changing the domain of $\otimes_C$ to $\text{Mod}^{\text{op}}\times C\text{Mod}$. Is this allowed? (i.e. is there some functor I can compose $\otimes_C$ with to change the domain to what I need?)

Comment: $\mathrm{Hom}_C(- \otimes_C -, X \otimes_C Y)$ is a functor $C\mathrm{Mod}^{\mathrm{op}} \times C\mathrm{Mod}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathrm{Set}$, since the opposite of a monoidal category is monoidal. The two arguments have to have to same variance.

Comment: You can consider $\hom(X\otimes-,\,Y\otimes-):C{\rm -Mod}^{op}\times C{\rm -Mod}\to C{\rm -Mod}$.